# Sistema de vidas en python no funciona

Tags: python, condiciones, while

Estaba elaborando un juego de quimica organica para un trabajo, y se presento la necesidad de darle niveles de dificultad, así que decidí implementar un sistema de vidas. Estuvo funcionando bien en los primeros niveles, pero al llegar a compuestos con más de una respuesta posible, dejaba de funcionar apropiadamente. Antes cada vez que se fallaba restaba una vida y daba la oportunidad de volver a intentar, ahora hace eso para llegar hasta llegar a cero vidas, pero cuando alcanza el cero, no importa lo que se escriba, te permite continuar a la siguiente pregunta. He revisado numerosas veces si es que defini mal las respuestas, pero todo parece en orden. Lo mismo va para la identacion. Este es el codigo:

```
import random 

Semi_prefijos_carbonos={1 : "metan", 2 : "etan", 3 : "propan", 4 : "butan", 5:"pentan", 6:"hexan", 7:"heptan", 8:"octan", 9:"nonan", 10:"decan", 11:"undecan", 12:"dodecan"}
Cetonas={3 : "propanona", 4 : "butanona", 5:"pentanona", 6:"hexanona", 7:"heptanona", 8:"octanona", 9:"nonanona", 10:"decanona", 11:"undecanona", 12:"dodecanona"} 
Radicales={1 : "metil", 2 : "etil", 3 : "propil", 4 : "butil", 5:"pentil", 6:"hexil", 7:"heptil", 8:"octil", 9:"nonil", 10:"decil", 11:"undecil", 12:"dodecil"}
Niveles_dificultad={"facil" : 3, "normal" : 2, "dificil" : 1}
Dificultad=input("Elige el nivel de dificultad, este determinara el numero de vidas (facil, normal, dificil): ")
vidas=Niveles_dificultad[Dificultad]
Carbonos=random.randint(3, 12)
Carbonos_cadena1=1
Carbonos_cadena2=Carbonos-2
cetonas=[str(Radicales[Carbonos_cadena1]), str(Radicales[Carbonos_cadena2])]
cetonas_ordenada=sorted(cetonas, key=str.lower) 
print("Escribe el nombre de la cetona con una cadena de "+str(Carbonos_cadena1)+" carbono a la izquierda, y otra cadena de "+str(Carbonos_cadena2)+" carbonos a la derecha.")
Respuesta=input("Escribes que es: ")
while Respuesta != str(cetonas_ordenada[0])+" "+str(cetonas_ordenada[1])+" cetona" and "2-"+str(Cetonas[Carbonos]) and str(Semi_prefijos_carbonos[Carbonos])+"2-ona" and vidas >= 1:
    vidas = vidas - 1
    print("(Respuesta incorrecta, pierdes una vida. Te quedan " + str(vidas) + ")")
    Respuesta=input("Vuelves a intentar diciendo que es: ")
if Respuesta==str(cetonas_ordenada[0])+" "+str(cetonas_ordenada[1])+" cetona" or "2-"+str(Cetonas[Carbonos]) or str(Semi_prefijos_carbonos[Carbonos])+"-2-ona":
    print("Agarras la muestra de "+str(Respuesta)+" y la metes en tu ivnentario.")
else:
    print("Perdiste")
```

Comment: Pareciese que el problema que tienes es que no existe una condición que pregunte si las vidas son iguales a cero y terminar el juego.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *[...] cuando alcanza el cero, no importa lo que se escriba, te permite continuar a la siguiente pregunta.*

A pesar de lo que ha mencionado [FranAcuna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/153371/franacuna) en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/410574/sistema-de-vidas-en-python-no-funciona#comment734371_410574), sí que pareces tener un condicional para el número de vidas:

```py
while respuesta != ··· and vidas >= 1:
```

De hecho, no he logrado que el código entre en un bucle infinito de ningún modo. ¿Es posible que hayas estado ejecutando un archivo distinto?

---

El único error de bulto que encuentro es que el resultado de las condiciones será incorrecto, ya que cualquier `str`, se evalúa por su longitud en las operaciones lógicas.

**Incorrecto**

```py
while respuesta != str(···) and str(···) and vidas >= 1:
    pass
```

En este caso, `str(···)` equivale a una cadena no vacía, por lo que es lo mismo que no poner ninguna condición adicional: `if respuesta == str(···) and True`

```py
if respuesta == str(···) or str(···) or vidas >= 1:
    pass
```

En este caso, `str(···)` también equivale a una cadena no vacía, por lo que la condición siempre se cumple. Es el equivalente a poner `if respuesta == str(···) or True`, o un **sí o sí** en el lenguaje coloquial.

**Correcto**

```py
while respuesta != str(···) and respuesta != str(···) and vidas >= 1:
    pass
if respuesta == str(···) or respuesta == str(···) or vidas >= 1:
    pass
```

Aquí comparamos la igualdad de `respuesta` con cada `str(···)` de forma independiente, obteniendo el resultado esperado.

**Alternativa**

```py
while respuesta not in (str(···), str(···), ···) and vidas >= 1:
    pass
if respuesta not in (str(···), str(···), ···) or vidas >= 1:
    pass
```

Muchas veces resulta más sencillo utilizar `not in` para saber si un valor se encuentra entre los elementos de un objeto del tipo `sequence` (como `list` o `tuple`, por ejemplo) o en las claves de un `dict` (diccionario de `{"clave": valor}` como el que ya usas).

---

De todas formas, el código tiene bastantes problemas de formato y he decidido hacerle algunas reformas. Si quieres, puedes leerte mi versión «mejorada» y utilizarla como base para continuar desarrollando el programa.

```py
import random


def calcular_soluciones(carbonos_izquierda: int, carbonos_derecha: int) -> tuple:
    """Calcula las posibles soluciones correctas para la cetona."""

    # Compone los textos prefijos y los ordena según el alfabeto.
    cetonas = sorted([
        componer_texto_prefijo(carbonos, "il")
        for carbonos in
        (carbonos_izquierda, carbonos_derecha)
        ])

    # Genera tres posibles variantes del nombre.
    variante_1 = " ".join(cetonas + ["cetona"])  # Unidos con espacios.
    variante_2 = componer_texto_prefijo(carbonos_derecha + 2, "an") + "-2-ona"
    variante_3 = "2-" + componer_texto_prefijo(carbonos_derecha + 2, "anona")

    return variante_1, variante_2, variante_3


def componer_texto_prefijo(número: int, sufijo: str = "a") -> str:
    """Devuelve el prefijo griego con el sufijo seleccionado."""
    prefijos = [
        "met", "et", "prop", "but",
        "pent", "hex", "hept", "oct",
        "non", "dec", "undec", "dodec"
        ]
    return prefijos[número - 1] + sufijo


def componer_texto_carbono(carbonos: int) -> str:
    """Compone un texto con el número de carbonos y las unidades."""
    if carbonos == 1:
        return "1 carbono"
    else:
        return f"{carbonos} carbonos"


def componer_texto_vidas(vidas: int) -> str:
    """Compone un texto informativo sobre las vidas restantes."""
    if vidas_restantes == 0:
        return "¡No te quedan vidas!"
    elif vidas_restantes == 1:
        return "¡Te queda una vida!"
    else:
        return f"Te quedan {vidas} vidas."


def mostrar_pregunta(carbonos_izquierda: int, carbonos_derecha: int):
    """Muestra la pregunta a cada ejercicio."""
    izquierda = componer_texto_carbono(carbonos_izquierda) + " a la izquierda"
    derecha = componer_texto_carbono(carbonos_derecha) + " a la derecha"
    cadenas = f"una cadena de {izquierda} y otra cadena de {derecha}"
    print(f"Escribe el nombre de la cetona con {cadenas}:")


def obtener_respuesta() -> str:
    """Obtiene un texto introducido por el usuario."""
    return input("> ").lower().strip()  # En minúsculas y sin espacios extra.


# Diccionario con los niveles y el número de vidas que lleva cada uno.
niveles = {"fácil": 3, "normal": 2, "difícil": 1}

# Muestra un listado de niveles y las vidas que lleva cada uno.
print("Selecciona el nivel de dificultad: ")
for nivel, vidas in niveles.items():
    print(f"* {nivel.title()}: {vidas} vidas.")

# Mientras el usuario no seleccione un nivel válido
while (nivel := obtener_respuesta()) not in niveles:
    print("Opción inválida; escribe el nombre del nivel bien acentuado.")

# Establece el número de vidas seleccionado.
vidas_restantes = niveles[nivel]


# Bucle infinito.
while True:
    print()  # Deja una línea en blanco entre preguntas.

    # Utiliza un carbono a la izquierda y entre [3, 12] al azar a la derecha.
    carbonos_izquierda, carbonos_derecha = 1, random.randint(3, 12) - 2

    # Obtiene las soluciones posibles para los carbonos especificados.
    soluciones = calcular_soluciones(carbonos_izquierda, carbonos_derecha)

    # Muestra el enunciado de la pregunta.
    mostrar_pregunta(carbonos_izquierda, carbonos_derecha)

    while vidas_restantes > 0:
        # Obtiene la respuesta y la convierte a minúsculas.
        respuesta = obtener_respuesta()

        # Si la respuesta está entre las correctas:
        if respuesta in soluciones:
            print(f"¡Correcto! Añade «{respuesta}» a tu inventario.")
            break  # Interrumpe el bucle.

        # Si la respuesta está vacía:
        elif not respuesta:
            print("¿No esperarás que te dé una pista, verdad?")

        # Si la respuesta es errónea:
        else:
            vidas_restantes -= 1
            print(f"¡Incorrecto! {componer_texto_vidas(vidas_restantes)}")

    # Si el bucle no ha sido interrumpido con "break".
    else:
        print("¡Perdiste!")  # Ha agotado las vidas sin acertar.
        break  # Interrumpe el bucle infinito y acaba el programa.
```